# Python - wrap same object to make it unique

Tags: python, python-2.7, object, unique, instance

I have a dictionary that is being built while iterating through objects. Now same object can be accessed multiple times. And I'm using object itself as a key.

So if same object is accessed more than once, then key becomes not unique and my dictionary is no longer correct.

Though I need to access it by object, because later on if someone wants access contents by it, they can request to get it by current object. And it will be correct, because it will access the last active object at that time.

So I'm wondering if it is possible to wrap object somehow, so it would keep its state and all attributes the same, but the only difference would be this new kind of object which is actually unique.

For example:

```
dct = {}

for obj in some_objects_lst:
    # Well this kind of wraps it, but it loses state, so if I would
    # instantiate I would lose all information that was in that obj.
    wrapped = type('Wrapped', (type(obj),), {})
    dct[wrapped] = # add some content
```

Now if there are some better alternatives than this, I would like to hear it too.

P.S. objects being iterated would be in different context, so even if object is the same, it would be treated differently.

**Update**

As requested, to give better example where the problem comes from:

I have this excel reports generator module. Using it, you can generate various excel reports. For that you need to write configuration using python dictionary.

Now before report is generated, it must do two things. Get metadata (metadata here is position of each cell that will be when report is about to be created) and second, parse configuration to fill cells with content.

One of the value types that can be used in this module, is formula (excel formulas). And the problem in my question is specifically with one of the ways formula can be computed: formula values that are retrieved for parent , that are in their childs.

For example imagine this excel file structure:

```
  A          | B          | C
  Total        Childs Name Amount
1 sum(childs)
2              child_1      10
3              child_2      20

4 sum(childs)
  ...
```

Now in this example sum on cell 1A, would need to be 10+20=30 if sum would use expression to sum their childs column (in this case `C` column). And all of this is working until same object (I call it iterables) is repeated. Because when building metadata it I need to store it, to retrieve later. And key is object being iterated itself. So now when it will be iterated again when parsing values, it will not see all information, because some will overwritten by same object.

For example imagine there are invoice objects, then there are partner objects which are related with invoices and there are some other arbitrary objects that given invoice and partner produce specific amounts.

So when extracting such information in excel, it goes like this:

```
inoice1 -> partner1 -> amount_obj1, amount_obj2
invoice2 -> partner1 -> amount_obj3, amount_obj4.
```

**Notice that partner in example is the same. Here is the problem, because I can't store this as key, because when parsing values, I will iterate over this object twice when metadata will actually hold values for `amount_obj3` and `amount_obj4`**

P.S Don't know if I explained it better, cause there is lots of code and I don't want to put huge walls of code here.

**Update2**

I'll try to explain this problem from more abstract angle, because it seems being too specific just confuses everyone even more.

So given objects list and empty dictionary, dictionary is built by iterating over objects. Objects act as a key in dictionary. It contains metadata used later on.

Now same list can be iterated again for different purpose. When its done, it needs to access that dictionary values using iterated object (same objects that are keys in that dictionary). But the problem is, if same object was used more than once, it will have only latest stored value for that key.

It means object is not unique key here. But the problem is the only thing I know is the object (when I need to retrieve the value). But because it is same iteration, specific index of iteration will be the same when accessing same object both times.

So uniqueness I guess then is `(index, object)`.

Comment: I find a contradiction with the 2nd paragraph (*the key becomes not unique and my dictionary is no longer correct*) and the 3rd one (*it will access the last active object at that time*): why replacing the value by something else a problem if accessing the last active object is ok ? It seems to me the default behaviour of a dict is fine for your problem.

Comment: Well I thought this too, but its not working. But maybe you are right and there is actually a bug in code, so I get different results than I expect (I'm expecting to get content from different part of dict, I mean different key)

Comment: Maybe you can give more context information on what you're doing in order to make it more clear ?

Comment: I don't understand your problem, but I can virtually guarantee that wrapping objects in the way you describe is not the solution. :)

Comment: @SvenMarnach probably you are right, but I can't grasp my head how to store that reference, because the only thing that is known when I need to retrieve it is object itself, but if its not unique, then here is this problem.

Comment: We would need some more context.  Trying a wild guess, how about using lists as dictionary values?  This will allow you to store multiple values for each key.  (Let me emphasise again that I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.)

Comment: In response to your update, how about using `index, obj` as the dictionary key then?  Like `dct[index, obj] = …`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I actually did something similar. Index was not a way to go, because I was wrong about it. It is not always the same. When iterating second time, index can actually be different (if there are multiple blocks of those objects). Though what worked, was to use multiple objects as a key: there are objects in a hierarchy tree and it is unique. So I used it. Now I can retrieve correct value. Though the question is, is it relevant for me to write answer? Cause I don't know if it would really answer my question directly:)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem, so here's two options. If it's object content that matters, keep object copies as a key. Something crude like

```
new_obj = copy.deepcopy(obj)
dct[new_obj] = whatever_you_need_to_store(new_obj)
```

If the object doesn't change between the first time it's checked by your code and the next, the operation is just performed the second time with no effect. Not optimal, but probably not a big problem. If it does change, though, you get separate records for old and new ones. For memory saving you will probably want to replace copies with hashes, `__str__()` method that writes object data or whatever. But that depends on what your object is; maybe hashing will take too much time for miniscule savings in memory. Run some tests and see what works.

If, on the other hand, it's important to keep the same value for the same object, whether the data within it have changed or not (say, object is a user session that can change its data between login and logoff), use object ids. Not the builtin `id()` function, because if the object gets GCed or deleted, some other object may get its id. Define an `id` attribute for your objects and make sure different objects cannot possibly get the same one.